# Error loading image path in Yii (GD)

Tags: php, image, yii, gd, yii-extensions

I recently changed hosts and a code that used to work in my previous host and also still works fine in my development is not working on my new host.

It deals with resizing and cropping an uploaded image and the line throwing the error is:

```
$gd = Yii::app()->image->load($dir . $file);
```

More specifically the following line in the image extension:

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.image.Image');
```

I checked other variables and the path is properly being input as :

```
/home/hostname/public_html/uploads/photos/105/0e639235e22d18ae5df5dcf137c1dbcc.jpg
```

Here is the error log:

```
> 2016/07/27 07:13:44 [error] [php] include(phpYii.php): failed to open
> stream: No such file or directory
> (/home/hostname/yii/framework/YiiBase.php:432) Stack trace:
> #0 /home/hostname/public_html/protected/extensions/image/CImageComponent.php(1):
> spl_autoload_call()
> #1 /home/hostname/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(321): require()
> #2 /home/hostname/yii/framework/YiiBase.php(196): import()
> #3 /home/hostname/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(393): createComponent()
> #4 /home/hostname/yii/framework/base/CModule.php(103): CWebApplication->getComponent()
> #5 /home/hostname/public_html/protected/models/Photo.php(136): CWebApplication->__get()
> #6 /home/hostname/public_html/protected/controllers/DefaultController.php(230):
> Photo->saveVarients()
> #7 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): DefaultController->actionUploadPhoto()
> #8 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
> #9 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/CController.php(286): DefaultController->runAction()
> #10 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/CController.php(265): DefaultController->runActionWithFilters()
> #11 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): DefaultController->run()
> #12 /home/hostname/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
> #13 /home/hostname/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): CWebApplication->processRequest()
> #14 /home/hostname/public_html/index.php(14): CWebApplication->run()
```

I tried to re-install the extension and config, but to no success. I am not sure what else I need to consider, since the code works on my development system and used to work on a previous host.

Comment: Is GD or ImageMagick installed on the server? Do a `phpinfo()` to check

Comment: Yep, I double checked that too.

Comment: Weird. You could also try `$gd = Yii::app()->image->load(getcwd() . $file);`. You might need to tweak the path a bit,`getcwd()` gets the current working directory. You did say the path is correct so this probably won't work but worth a try

Comment: I am afraid the path returned by either method is the same. No joy.

Comment: Must be a server config issue if it was working before. Maybe check permissions on the directory you are writing to, and check the max upload size for the server.

Comment: I see the image being uploaded to the folder where it should go, and can also view that by typing the link in the browser. It's the GD processing that breaks the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118451/discussion-between-eskimo-and-shahid-thaika).